# PHP_iisfunc.dll is crashing wil i am trying access the detail for upload

Tags: php

Faulting application Apache.exe, version 2.0.63.200, faulting module php_iisfunc.dll, version 
5.2.7.7, fault address 0x00001085.

Any one having any idea about above error it thrown in Event view and crashes the apache server

Comment: how about posting the code that causes the crash? did you try similar implementations?

Comment: Yeah, more info about the code please.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the IIS management functions to handle an IIS server through Apache? If not, just inactivate that extension in your php.ini

You can read more about that extension here:
http://kromann.info/article.php?Id=11062861865960000

I guess it's crashing because you're running an Apache server. Do you even have IIS installed?

Comment: if i inactivate the dll then also it is crashing...coz, i am not having IIS installed on my machine....it show similar message but instead of dll name it shows Unknown.